# how to write c# that control over external cmd

Tags: c#, java, cmd

I need some suggestion. I am almost finish with my program but stuck at the final step.
I am trying to run a java file from C# using:

Process.start("java","file")  //with file = file.class (already compiled java filed)

the process will fire a cmd and execute the java file
everything work fine but the cmd close too fast, it doesn't matter whether my java file ask for input or not, at the end, after completion, cmd just automatically close.

Since cmd is external application, I have no control over it in C#:
used Process.WaitForExit(); but same effect because cmd, as i said, external

is there anyway I can pause cmd using c#, or set up cmd somehow so it will not close (just once, not every times i want to run lol).  I want to see the output

this has to be done without any modification to java because i will be running multiple java files in the same way.

Comment: Can you run multiple commands in one such as `java file ; pause` ?

Comment: the java file should be unknown, either take in output or no, can be simple helloworld, or asking and print your age. But the java file should not be modified, in another word I do not have privilege to edit the content of it.

Comment: But can you run multiple commands like a mini-script i.e. your java program and `pause` ?

Comment: i can do anything is c#, but not java file. let say java file will print out hello world, that's it. It does print, but then cmd exit to fast, I can't see the result!

Comment: Matthew help me and got it to work, tyvm for your time!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905352/any-way-to-keep-an-external-command-window-open-during-a-process-start

Comment: My point is; you don't have to change java at all. You just have to run a script which runs java and does what you want. Matthew's solution is the simplest solution in this case, but if you need something more complicated you can use a script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Process.Start("cmd", "/K java test.class");
```

The `/K` flag tells `cmd` to run the supplied command but not to close the window afterwards.

Comment: it true that the cmd will popup, and pause until i exit. But then I need to type in: java test to run my java file. since i will run alot of java files, is there anyway to run it automatically?

Comment: fyi, the file that i want to run is .class file, so I have to said Process.Start("java","javafile"), just like how we manually run in cmd.

Comment: I've edited my answer to clarify what I meant. Does this work for you?

Comment: Man, you are genius. Just as what I want. Thanks alot. Now how do I mark this post as [SOLVED], my first time here at SO :)

Comment: Cool. Glad it helped you out :-)