# With Process.Start(), How can I keep cmd prompt open when the /K argument doesn't work?

Tags: c#, cmd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Any way to keep an external command window open during a Process.Start(..)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905352/any-way-to-keep-an-external-command-window-open-during-a-process-start)

I've seen this post before but those solutions don't work for me for some reason. With Process.Start(), How can I keep cmd prompt open when the /K argument doesn't work? There's also no "WaitForExit" method available.

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/K " + "C:\\Windows\\System32\\" + "takeown.exe");
processInfo.Verb = "runas";
processInfo.Arguments = "/F \"C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Borland\" /R /D Y";
Process.Start(processInfo);
```

What I want to see is if the process processed successfully.

Thanks

Comment: `WaitForExit` [is a method, not a property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13732822/7724).

Comment: This question appears here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905352/any-way-to-keep-an-external-command-window-open-during-a-process-start

Comment: @bzlm Your right, sorry.

Comment: @TheGreatCO Saw that but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can wait for the process to finish before continuing:

```
var process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.WaitForExit();
if (process.ExitCode != 0) {
    // Handle failure...
}
```

Comment: The WaitForExit method isn't available as an option. Why would that be?

Comment: @Jim: No idea. According to MSDN it's been there since .NET 1.1.

Comment: Well Cameron I'm not sure what happened but I closed the IDE and restarted it and now I have that method. And it does the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
processInfo.Verb = "runas";
processInfo.Arguments = "/K C:\\Windows\\System32\takeown.exe /F \"C:\\Program Files(x86)\\Borland\" /R /D Y";
Process.Start(processInfo);
```