# Prevent command prompt from closing after running code (visual C#)?

Tags: c#, cmd

I'm trying to run a code on command prompt using this code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Cmd");
startInfo.Arguments = "/c tracert 8.8.8.8";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

But it closes after running code but I want cmd stay open. What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13732740/with-process-start-how-can-i-keep-cmd-prompt-open-when-the-k-argument-doesn

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `/c` argoument is telling CMD to close after the instructions are done.

Instead, if you want to keep the window open and return to the terminal, you should use the `/k` switch:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Cmd");
startInfo.Arguments = "/k tracert 8.8.8.8";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: to see all available switches, call `cmd /?` from the windows prompt

Answer (score 1):

Add a `pause` command

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("Cmd");
startInfo.Arguments = "/c tracert 8.8.8.8 & pause";
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
startInfo.Arguments = "/K /c tracert 8.8.8.8";
```

Comment: why both `k` an `c` ?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.